# Converting time intervals into time/person matrix

Tags: r, datetime, optimization, plyr, data-conversion

I'm working on a history project, where we need to get an overview of the numbers of employees at each month. For each person in the data set I have the periods where they were employed. The fname_code codes for different job positions. To exemplify, Dr. Edmont Privat had two different functions in the respective periods shown below:

```
                             pname  fname_code begin_date   end_date
1                 Dr. Edmond Privat          3 1921-09-02 1921-10-07
2                 Dr. Edmond Privat          2 1921-12-07 1922-03-06
3 Joseph Louis Marie Charles Avenol          1 1923-02-01 1933-07-01
4 Joseph Louis Marie Charles Avenol          1 1933-07-01 1940-08-31
5               Dr. G. G.  Kullmann          2 1931-03-30 1938-12-15
```

My idea is to convert this information into a subject/date period dataframe/matrix, where N indicates that the person wasn't in the company at this point, while numbers indicate that they were hired and the rank they had. Here's an example of what I have in mind:

```
                               1944-07-01 1944-08-01 1944-09-01 1944-10-01 
Albert Dan Meurig Evans                 N          N          N          N               
Genevieve Jeanne Leonie Mayor           N          2          3          3
```

I've made a something which does the job - it has made the above lines - however, the code is definetley not for the feint hearted programmers (lots of foreloops!). My question is if any of you experienced programmers have suggestions for improving the speed, or obtain my goal in a radically different way.
I've tried play around with some dplyr functions, but I have too little experience with them to make them work. I've also considered creating an if-condition to handle the cases where a person just has been hired for a single period, since in that case a forloop isn't necessary - But I'm not sure where to implement it optimally.

The logic of my computational disaster is to see if there are overlaps between month intervals from the data frame and the employment data frame:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
#creating sequence of dates for columns
start_date <- as.Date("1919-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("1948-12-30")
dates <- seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by ="month")

#dates as columns and names on columns
test.df <- matrix(ncol =length(dates), nrow = nlevels(mdl_df$pname))
test.df <- as.data.frame(test.df)
colnames(test.df) <- dates
rownames(test.df) <- levels(mdl_df$pname)

for (name in 1:nlevels(mdl_df$pname)){ 
#subsetting the rows for each person
  person_rows <- mdl_df %>% filter( mdl_df$pname == rownames(test.df)[name]) 


  for (date in 1:(length(dates)-1)) { 

    #Creating a month interval consisting of the time between two adjecent months
    interval1 <- interval(ymd(colnames(test.df)[date]),ymd(colnames(test.df)[date+1]))  

    for (row in 1:nrow(person_rows)) {
        #check if overlap between df month interval and employment intervals.

       interval2 <- interval(ymd(person_rows$begin_date[row]),ymd(person_rows$end_date[row]))    

       if (int_overlaps(interval1, interval2)){
       #checking if df period and work period overlap. If so rank is inserted otherwise N is entered

         test.df[name,date] <- test_rows$fname_code[row]
         break
       }else{
         test.df[name,date] <- "N"
    }
   }    
  }
}
```

The dataset consists of around 3000 employees, and it will take my computer around 6-7 hours to do the job. I would need to run and re-run the script several times over the next weeks on various data sets, so any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: dput output for the first 50 rows of dataset.

```
> dput(droplevels(head(mdl_df, 50)))
structure(list(pname = structure(c(7L, 7L, 24L, 24L, 8L, 19L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 34L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 23L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 32L, 5L, 22L, 29L, 3L, 13L, 25L, 2L, 6L, 26L, 18L, 
21L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 20L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 31L, 
33L, 30L, 30L, 1L), .Label = c("A. Gordon Bagnall", "Bertil Gotthard Ohlin", 
"Birgit Nissen", "Bryan Fullerton Adams", "C.H. Wykes", "Christian Olsen", 
"Dr. Edmond Privat", "Dr. G. G.  Kullmann", "EugÃ¨ne Henri RenÃ©  Vigier", 
"Ewan P. Wallis-Jones", "Francis Yeats-Brown", "Francisco Walker-Linares", 
"Frank Horsfall Nixon", "Frank Paul Walters", "Franklin Urteaga", 
"Gerald Heguerty Furtado Abraham", "Gladys Wade", "Guillaume ThÃ©odore Conrad Zwerner", 
"Henri Bonnet", "Haakon Vigander", "Ignacio J. Valdes", "Ingvad Nielsen", 
"Jessie Irene Wall", "Joseph Louis Marie Charles Avenol", "Julian Nogueira", 
"Konni Zilliacus", "Luis Varela-Obregoso", "Marc Veillet-Lavallee", 
"Maria Nielsen", "Peter Martin Anker", "Pierre Achille Louis EugÃ¨ne Quesnay", 
"Pierre Henry Watier", "Prof. Fred Alexander", "Robert AndrÃ© Felix Bach"
), class = "factor"), fname_code = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), begin_date = structure(c(-17653, 
-17557, -17136, -13333, -14157, -17897, -18050, -13789, -8962, 
-15010, -11810, -15372, -14003, -14855, -16047, -12900, -18494, 
-18254, -14245, -13333, -11172, -12008, -18398, -14360, -15002, 
-11802, -17883, -12862, -14245, -17136, -18248, -14975, -13989, 
-15494, -15372, -14108, -14738, -18201, -17849, -17849, -11657, 
-10592, -10579, -10130, -11436, -16849, -13631, -14033, -11161, 
-12620), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(-17618, -17468, 
-13333, -10715, -11340, -14243, -13789, -11223, -8624, -11178, 
-10797, -17543, -13982, -8555, -15628, -12879, -18254, -14245, 
-13333, -11172, -10809, -11822, -18255, -14339, -14988, -11781, 
-17078, -11158, -13958, -16590, -11401, -14610, -13968, -15434, 
-15007, -13920, -14717, -17849, -8524, -8524, -8524, -8524, -8524, 
-8524, -11415, -15707, -13613, -11161, -8555, -12614), class = "Date")), 
.Names = c("pname", "fname_code", "begin_date", "end_date"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running Rstudio v.1.0.136

Packages attached:

```
[1] dplyr_0.7.1     purrr_0.2.2.2   readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3    ggplot2_2.2.1  
[7] tidyverse_1.1.1 lubridate_1.6.0
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` so that we can reproduce your dataset?

Comment: Of course, added as an edit now.

Comment: You need to add package dependencies.

Comment: Yes sir, information also added as edit:
Running Rstudio v.1.0.136.

Packages attached:

[1] dplyr_0.7.1     purrr_0.2.2.2   readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3    ggplot2_2.2.1  
[7] tidyverse_1.1.1 lubridate_1.6.0

Comment: I meant that you need to include the `library` code so thta your code is reproducible.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm just loading the following two packages, also added to the code above now:

library(lubridate),
library(tidyverse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.9.8 of the `data.table` package (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016) introduced *non-equi joins* which are very useful here to find the overlaps of employment times with month intervals. `dcast()` is then used to reshape from long to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
setDT(mdl_df)[
  # right join with sequence of monthly intervals
  .(mseq = seq(as.Date("1944-01-01"), length.out = 4L, by = "1 month")), 
  # using non-equi join conditions
  on = .(begin_date <= mseq, end_date >= mseq)][
    # reshape from wide to long format,
    # show rank (concatenate in case of multiple ranks)
    , dcast(unique(.SD), pname ~ end_date, toString, value.var = "fname_code")]
```

> ```
>                          pname    1944-01-01    1944-02-01    1944-03-01    1944-04-01
> 1: EugÃ¨ne Henri RenÃ©  Vigier 0, 1, 2, 3, 6 0, 1, 2, 3, 6 0, 1, 2, 3, 6 0, 1, 2, 3, 6
> 2:    Francisco Walker-Linares             4             4             4             4
> 3:          Peter Martin Anker             2             2             2             2
> ```

---

#### Edit

[In his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941463/converting-time-intervals-into-time-person-matrix/45945139?noredirect=1#comment78855858_45945139), the OP has requested to cover the period 1919-01-01 to 1948-12-30. Here, we need to modify the join parameters:

```
result <- setDT(mdl_df)[
  .(mseq = seq(as.Date("1919-01-01"), as.Date("1948-12-30"), by = "1 month")), 
  on = .(begin_date <= mseq, end_date >= mseq), nomatch = 0L, allow.cartesian = TRUE][
    , dcast(unique(.SD), pname ~ end_date, toString, value.var = "fname_code")]
```

`result` consists of 27 rows and 328 columns which can only be printed in parts:

```
result[, 1:5]
```

> ```
>                                    pname 1919-06-01 1919-07-01 1919-08-01 1919-09-01
>  1:                Bertil Gotthard Ohlin                                            
>  2:                Bryan Fullerton Adams                                            
>  3:                           C.H. Wykes                                           2
>  4:                      Christian Olsen                                            
>  5:                    Dr. Edmond Privat                                            
>  6:                  Dr. G. G.  Kullmann                                            
>  7:          EugÃ¨ne Henri RenÃ©  Vigier                                            
>  8:             Francisco Walker-Linares                                            
>  9:                 Frank Horsfall Nixon                                            
> 10:                   Frank Paul Walters          3          3          3          3
> 11:                     Franklin Urteaga                                            
> 12:      Gerald Heguerty Furtado Abraham                                            
> 13:                          Gladys Wade                                            
> 14:   Guillaume ThÃ©odore Conrad Zwerner                                            
> 15:                         Henri Bonnet                                            
> 16:                      Haakon Vigander                                            
> 17:                    Ignacio J. Valdes                                            
> 18:                    Jessie Irene Wall                                            
> 19:    Joseph Louis Marie Charles Avenol                                            
> 20:                      Julian Nogueira                                            
> 21:                      Konni Zilliacus                                            
> 22:                 Luis Varela-Obregoso                                            
> 23:                Marc Veillet-Lavallee                                            
> 24:                   Peter Martin Anker                                            
> 25: Pierre Achille Louis EugÃ¨ne Quesnay                                            
> 26:                  Pierre Henry Watier                                            
> 27:             Robert AndrÃ© Felix Bach                                            
>                                    pname 1919-06-01 1919-07-01 1919-08-01 1919-09-01
> ```

Note that the first date shown is 1919-06-01 because there are no earlier matches. Likewise, the last column 328 is 1946-08-01.

```
result[, c(1, 328 - 2:0)]
```

> ```
>                                    pname    1946-06-01    1946-07-01    1946-08-01
>  1:                Bertil Gotthard Ohlin                                          
>  2:                Bryan Fullerton Adams                                          
>  3:                           C.H. Wykes                                          
>  4:                      Christian Olsen                                          
>  5:                    Dr. Edmond Privat                                          
>  6:                  Dr. G. G.  Kullmann                                          
>  7:          EugÃ¨ne Henri RenÃ©  Vigier 0, 1, 2, 3, 6 0, 1, 2, 3, 6 0, 1, 2, 3, 6
>  8:             Francisco Walker-Linares             4             4              
>  9:                 Frank Horsfall Nixon                                          
> 10:                   Frank Paul Walters                                          
> 11:                     Franklin Urteaga                                          
> 12:      Gerald Heguerty Furtado Abraham                                          
> 13:                          Gladys Wade                                          
> 14:   Guillaume ThÃ©odore Conrad Zwerner                                          
> 15:                         Henri Bonnet                                          
> 16:                      Haakon Vigander                                          
> 17:                    Ignacio J. Valdes                                          
> 18:                    Jessie Irene Wall                                          
> 19:    Joseph Louis Marie Charles Avenol                                          
> 20:                      Julian Nogueira                                          
> 21:                      Konni Zilliacus                                          
> 22:                 Luis Varela-Obregoso                                          
> 23:                Marc Veillet-Lavallee                                          
> 24:                   Peter Martin Anker             2             2              
> 25: Pierre Achille Louis EugÃ¨ne Quesnay                                          
> 26:                  Pierre Henry Watier                                          
> 27:             Robert AndrÃ© Felix Bach                                          
>                                    pname    1946-06-01    1946-07-01    1946-08-01
> ```

---

Note that `mdl_df` has `mdl_df[, uniqueN(pname)]` 34 unique names while `result` has only 27. This is due to inconsistent data, i.e., `begin_date` later `end_date` or too short periods:

```
# anti-join
mdl_df[!result, on = "pname"]
```

> ```
>                   pname fname_code begin_date   end_date
> 1:  Francis Yeats-Brown          2 1927-12-01 1921-12-21
> 2: Ewan P. Wallis-Jones          2 1934-09-07 1934-09-28
> 3:       Ingvad Nielsen          2 1930-09-08 1930-09-29
> 4:        Maria Nielsen          2 1928-12-05 1928-12-19
> 5:        Birgit Nissen          2 1937-09-09 1937-09-30
> 6: Prof. Fred Alexander          2 1932-09-06 1932-09-24
> 7:    A. Gordon Bagnall          2 1935-06-14 1935-06-20
> ```

Comment: I'm lacking precision in my question: It should be run for time period 1919-01-01 to 1948-12-30. When I make this change to sequencing I get an error I can't fix: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 127739 rows; more than 4981 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). 
Any suggestions?